# Wordpress URL rewrite

Tags: wordpress, url

I am trying to merge my custom made directory site together with my wordpress site in one domain.

There seems to be issues with the url being redirected to my wordpress categories. How can i rewrite url in wordpress to compliment my directory site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. Category, tag, page, post etc. slugs could collide with your directory names. You would have to either create a filter for WP to redirect specific URLs to your old content or modify your .htaccess file. Both methods are extremely complicated if you have a lot of pages, and overkill if you have only a few.

Why not migrate your old content to WP? Or if you don't want to do that, install WP into a subdirectory of your site, like /blog.